# Рефакторинг фильтрации

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Подскажите, как можно отрефакторить такой метод фильтрации:

```
 filterTasks(tasks) {
switch (this.state.currentFilter) {
  case TaskList.filters.description: {
    const sortedTasks = tasks.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.description > b.description;
    });
    if (this.state.isFilterReverse) {
      return sortedTasks.reverse();
    }
    return sortedTasks;
  }
  case TaskList.filters.status: {
    const sortedTasks = tasks.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.status > b.status;
    });
    if (this.state.isFilterReverse) {
      return sortedTasks.reverse();
    }
    return sortedTasks;
  }
  case TaskList.filters.task: {
    const sortedTasks = tasks.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.name > b.name;
    });
    if (this.state.isFilterReverse) {
      return sortedTasks.reverse();
    }
    return sortedTasks;
  }
  case TaskList.filters.priority: {
    const sortedTasks = tasks.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.priority > b.priority;
    });
    if (this.state.isFilterReverse) {
      return sortedTasks.reverse();
    }
    return sortedTasks;
  }
  default:
    return tasks;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передайте в качестве второго параметра `field` (имя поля по которому нужна сортировка), тогда вам даже `switch` - `case` не нужен

```
filterTasks(tasks, field) {
    const sortedTasks = tasks.sort((a, b) => {
       return a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1;
    });
    if (this.state.isFilterReverse) {
       return sortedTasks.reverse();
    }
    return sortedTasks;
}
```

Comment: Функция в sort должна возвращать 1, -1 или 0. Надо бы тоже поправить и указать на это.